# How to control audio playback in a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, raspberry-pi, playback

I am building a Telegram bot installed on my Raspberry Pi that will perform multiple functions. One of those is to play/pause/stop a 10-hours mp3 file in the Raspberry. So what I need is to control the audio playback with telegram messages.

To simplify it, I can save some instructions into a .txt file, and another python (or shell) script will check for those and perform an action to the audio player.

I am able to reproduce a file on the Raspberry's headphone jack using [omxplayer](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/audio/):

```
omxplayer -o local --no-keys /home/pi/Desktop/10hRock.mp3 &
```

But `omxplayer` has no stop/pause commands. You can press p/s while the command is running whithout `--no-keys`, but as far as I know python doesn't support this. I have tried `os.system()`.

So my question is: is there a library that handles mp3 file playback, **AND** allows me to choose between the HDMI or the headphone jack output? (Or a simple way to make sure audio goes always through the jack)

If there's another way to handle this, I'll be glad to try it out!

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest going with [VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings)

```
pip install python-vlc
```

And then simply:

```
import vlc
from time import sleep

p = vlc.MediaPlayer(audio_file_path)
p.play()
sleep(2)
p.pause()
sleep(2)
p.play()
sleep(2)
p.stop()
```

Concerning the change in audio output, its a bit more tricky, looking around, you can start with something along these lines:

```
instance = vlc.Instance()
mediaPlayer = instance.media_player_new()
mediaPlayer.set_mrl(audio_file_path)
device_list = instance.audio_output_enumerate_devices()
for dev in device_list:
    print(dev)
```

And here on Windows I'm stuck, because I don't get any device ID and can't seem to set the output.
Anyway, after that you can apply these methods to the player:

```
mediaPlayer.audio_output_set(device_name)
mediaPlayer.audio_output_device_set(device_name,device_ID)
```

checkout some topics on the [VLC Forum](https://forum.videolan.org/)

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of research going on! Thanks! I'll definitively try it out during this week and mark this answer as correct if it works :D

Comment: @EricRoy : So where you able to set the output device as desired on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Well, I first looked for the audio device on the VLC app, and once I got it I could set it. I found it easier than printing all devices, but that worked as well, so thank you!! :D

Comment: Oh nice, simple and effective :)